# strongly typed model /need output in model format

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

actually i'm new to this technology, i am using mvc2 architecture. l cant able to load the data from my model to view page. i used strongly typed model EventListing.Models.EventInfo. i need output in model format. how can i use my select function

Model

```
public class EventInfo  
    {            
        public int OPR { get; set; }
        public int EVENT_ID { get; set; }
        public string  SUBSITE { get; set; }
public static DataTable Select()
        {
            DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
            Dbhelper DbHelper = new Dbhelper();
            DbCommand cmd = DbHelper.GetSqlStringCommond("SELECT * FROM WS_EVENTINFO");
            myDataTable.Load(DbHelper.ExecuteReader(cmd));
            return myDataTable;
        }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult List()
        {            
            return View(EventModel.EventList());
        }
```

View

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<EventListing.Models.EventInfo>" %>
<% foreach (var model in EventListing.Models.EventModel.EventList())
                   { %>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%= Html.ActionLink(model.TITLE, "Detail", new { id = model.EVENT_ID })%>
```

Comment: Your controller doesn't actually call the model you've provided.  I would suggest that you need to actually select your data in a way you get a `List` of `EventInfo` objects to start, and show the `EventModel.EventList()` code.  The question is unanswerable as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to clean up your code a little:

```
public class EventInfo  
{            
    public int OPR { get; set; }
    public int EVENT_ID { get; set; }
    public string SUBSITE { get; set; }

    ... some other properties that you might want to use

    public static IEnumerable<EventInfo> Select()
    {
        var helper = new Dbhelper();
        using (var cmd = helper.GetSqlStringCommond("SELECT * FROM WS_EVENTINFO"))
        using (var reader = helper.ExecuteReader(cmd))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return new EventInfo
                {
                    OPR = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("OPR")),
                    EVENT_ID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("EVENT_ID")),
                    SUBSITE = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("SUBSITE"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then in the controller action:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
    var model = EventInfo.Select().ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally in the view:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<EventInfo>>" %>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%= Html.ActionLink(item.TITLE, "Detail", new { id = item.EVENT_ID }) %>
    </td>
...
```

The next improvement that should be done to this is to externalize the data access (the Select static method) into a separate repository and have the controller use this repository instead of directly invoking the Select method to query the database.